# Cannot find module 'enzyme' from 'src/setupTests.js'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a react component using both jest and enzyme, i've installed the necessary package for them, then configured my setupTests.js as shown below, but still have the same error that Enzyme module is not found, and "shallow" as well.
this is where i am trying to use Shallow from enzyme

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import { shallow } from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17"  
//some necessary  local imports
// some other tests
describe('Welcome Component', () => {
it('renders Button component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Welcome />);
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<NextButton text={"Next"}/>)).toEqual(true);
}); 
});
```

this is my setupTests.js

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "react-app",
     "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
     "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
     "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
     "@fontsource/rubik": "^4.5.0",
     "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
     "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
     "@mui/material": "^5.2.3",
     "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
     "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
     "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
     "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
     "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
     "ajv": "^8.8.2",
     "axios": "^0.24.0",
     "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
     "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
     "formik": "^2.2.9",
     "fs": "0.0.1-security",
     "icomoon-react": "^2.0.19",
     "jest": "^27.4.5",
     "jodit-react": "^1.1.11",
     "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
     "lodash": "^4.17.21",
     "lodash-redux-immutability": "0.0.3",
     "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
     "react": "^17.0.2",
     "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
     "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.6",
     "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
     "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
     "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
     "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
     "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
     "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
     "react-split": "^2.0.13",
     "react-split-pane": "^0.1.92",
     "react-toast-notifications": "^2.5.1",
     "react-web-vector-icons": "^1.0.2",
     "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
     "redux-subscriber": "^1.1.0",
     "reselect": "^4.1.5",
     "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
     "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
     "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
     "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
     "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
     ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
       ">0.2%",
       "not dead",
       "not op_mini all"
      ],
     "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
     ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
      "sass": "^1.43.2",
      "sass-loader": "^12.2.0"
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, official enzyme adapter unfortunately doesn't support react 17 yet, here I see you are using a package called @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17. I can share my configuration, with react 17 and enzyme adapter for react 16, which works together.

Comment: Thank you for your response,that sounds great, may you share it with me please.

Comment: You have React Testing Library (RTL), and imported `render`. If it's acceptable in your project, I would recommend to use RTL to render and test your components, as it encourages better testing practices than Enzyme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install all these dependencies in dev. In my case I am using typescript, if
   you are using javascript, skip types. Run npm i -D and all these
   dependencies.

   @types/enzyme
   @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16
   enzyme
   enzyme-adapter-react-16
   jest-environment-enzyme
   jest-enzyme
   @testing-library/jest-dom
   @testing-library/react
   @testing-library/user-event
   @types/jest
   ts-jest
2. In root of your project, create a file named **jest.config.js**  and inside put this code :

> module.exports = {
> preset: 'ts-jest',
> testEnvironment: 'node',
> modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["/dist/"],
> };

3. In the same root of the project, create a file called **jest.config.unit.js** and put this code there:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   preset: 'ts-jest',
>   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
>   modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/dist/"],
>   setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-enzyme"],
>   setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/setupEnzyme.ts'],
>   // ignore .js files
>   testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test))\\.[t]sx?$',
>   coverageReporters: ["lcov", "text"],
>   coverageDirectory: "test-coverage",
>   coverageThreshold: {
>     global: {
>       branches: 0,
>       functions: 0,
>       lines: 0,
>       statements: 0
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```

4. Go to src folder, and create this file: **setupEnzyme.ts(js)**, inside put this code:

> ```
> import { configure } from 'enzyme';
> import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
>
> configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
> ```

5. In src folder, create a file **setupTests.ts(js)** and put this code inside:

> import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

6. Finally go to package.json, and under the scripts add this

> "test": "jest -c jest.config.unit.js",

You are all set up. Create some test component, like Test.js which returns a simple div. Create a correspondent Test.test.js and add this test code:

> ```
> import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
> import { Test } from './test';
>
> describe('<Test /> renders correctly', () => {
>   it('Renders correctly', () => {
>     const wrapper = shallow(<Test />);
>     expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
>   });
> });
> ```

And if you run npm run test it should work.